# How to implement code controlling the robot

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

Currently i'm taking care of a project from another student, who just vanished since two months - but my dep still needs the project finished. So i have to dig into the system fast und get the whole simulation to run.

The setup is - as far as i can see - an ROS Hydro server with a husky as robot. The client from gazebo is used to view the simulation. The problem is, that i only get the husky to move via the rostopic command, but not through code.
The goal of the simulation-setup is to run java code, that controls the robot depending on the output of the sensors. I already understood that rosjava will be needed, but this isn't installed on the server - i will have to take care of that.

So, my question is - how can i control the robot via c++ code? In the tutorials i only got information about how to send messages and about the filesystem and so on. Did i missread the whole thing? It would be really nice if someone could dip my face into it :D

Thanks in advance,
Nathan

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/106511/how-to-implement-code-controlling-the-robot/) by [Nathan Schwarz](https://answers.ros.org/users/9411/nathan-schwarz/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-12-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can publish to a ROS topic from C++ code. Please refer to [this tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29) for details. You should be able to do the same from any of the other languages implementing ROS clients, like Python or Java.

---

Originally posted by [Adolfo Rodriguez T](https://answers.ros.org/users/410/adolfo-rodriguez-t/) with karma: 3907 on 2013-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Nathan Schwarz](https://answers.ros.org/users/9411/nathan-schwarz/) on 2013-12-05**:
Thanks, i got the entire tutorial wrong, i think :D
I will reread the whole thing, thanks for the help!